# Function structure: "if error, early return" or "if error, assign, else, assign, return assigned value"?

Tags: c, if-statement, return

In the context of embedded systems, given the following function structures:

1. Conditional assignement to return variable:

   ```
   int foo(int x)
   {
       int status;

       if (is_valid(x))
       {
           /* long computation with x */
           status = /* some result */;
       }
       else
           status = STATUS_ERROR;

       return status;
   }
   ```
2. Early return:

   ```
   int foo(int x)
   {
       if (!is_valid(x))
           return STATUS_ERROR;

       /* long computation with x */
       return /* some result */;
   }
   ```

In my opinion, the latter should be preferred over the former as:

- It doesn't require extra and unnecessary definition and assignments for `status`;
- It clearly states to the reader that in case of an error, nothing is done except from returning `STATUS_ERROR`, which is written at the start of the function, in the clearest way the language permits;
- It allows the code for the normal case to be flatter as it doesn't have to be indented for the `if`-`else`.

However, I have seen the former being used in a few different projects. I believe that the reasons for this might be related to the debugging step of development, to allow:

- having a single point of return, allowing easier breakpoint placement;
- inspection of the soon-to-be returned value through `status` (in particular at that single return).

Am I right in assuming that this is done for debugging? Are there other reasons to prefer 1. over 2.? Is 1. considered *good practice* in the context of baremetal development?

Please note that, unlike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011048), no work is done before returning the error code in case of an invalid `x`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/788903/6872717

Comment: The Linux kernel coding style prefers the second example. But it is a matter of preferences, more than if you are debugging or not.

Comment: It's usually better to use the second approach, where you test something and report the error, then potentially test something else and report the error, and finally do the main operation, reporting success.  When there's only one test, it is still better to put the smaller chunk of code (the error reporting) first because it is easier to recognize the chunks of the program.  In the first case you're hiding the information about the error case at the bottom, miles from the test that triggered the condition.  Early returns are often beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you asked if one should use one or the other, this would be an opinion-based question, and should be closed.

But this question seems to ask if there is any fact that makes you decide between the two, or if it is just a matter of taste, so it seems a valid question to me.

The answer is short, there is no objective difference between both; it's as simple as which one you feel more comfortable with (or if you have to follow a coding style).